# Why is the function part of the derivative answer for this problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[(x^3-x^2+5)(x^4-3x^2+7x)\right]$$

The answer is:

$$(3x^2 - 2x + 5)(x^4-3x^2 + 7x) + (x^3-x^2 +5x)(4x^3-6x+7)$$

Why is the function part of the answer?

Comment: Not sure what is your question.  The derivative maps a function to a different but related function.  your 7 th degree polynomial has mapped to a 6th degree polynomial.

Comment: It is not. I do not see $x^7 - x^6 + 2 x^5 + 10 x^4 - 22 x^3 + 35 x^2$ anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is the template for taking the derivative of a **product of functions**:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\big (f(x)\cdot g(x)\big) = f'(x)\cdot g(x) + f(x)\cdot g'(x)$$

---

In your case, we have:

$$\frac d{dx}\left[\underbrace{(x^3 -x^2 + 5x)}_{\large f(x)}\underbrace{(x^4-3x^2+7x)}_{\large g(x)}\right]$$

by the product rule for derivatives,

$$= \underbrace{(3x^2 - 2x + 5)}_{\large f'(x)}\underbrace{(x^4-3x^2 + 7x)}_{\large g(x)}\;\; + \;\;\underbrace{(x^3 - x^2 + 5x)}_{\large f(x)}\underbrace{(4x^3 - 6x+7)}_{\large g'(x)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Treat your function as the product of two functions $f$ and $g$. Hence

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \Big(f(x)\cdot g(x)\Big) = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$$

I think it's straightforward to understand this.